# Why did Armand do nothing to help Claudia and Louis?

Tags: vampire-chronicles, interview-with-the-vampire

In the movie adaptation of *Interview with the Vampire*, Armand tells Louis that it's illegal to make an immortal child; a slight difference from the book, where he's made it illegal in his own coven.  Armand clearly loves Louis and wants to do everything in his power to stay with him.

However, when Armand's coven captures Louis, Claudia, and Claudia's new companion, they then proceed to put Louis in a box and kill the other two (a glaring difference between the movie and the book, where Claudia is placed on trial for attempting to kill her maker; Lestat's testimony is what condemns her do death).  Armand does nothing to stop this, but that night, he goes to rescue Louis, who proceeds to slaughter Armand's entire coven.

**Why did Armand not stop his own people from doing what they did?  Did he not understand that by allowing them to kill Claudia, he would lose Louis forever and eventually be left alone?**

Comment: Armand is a complex individual with a *really* troubled past, a fanatical all-or-nothing worldview, a superiority complex, and an inferiority complex.  Don't be too hard on the guy.

Answer (score 3):

I feel his reason for not helping Claudia was so that he could have Louis to himself. Claudia had attempted to make a new family for Louis (herself in place of his own son; the woman in place of his wife). Without the two of them "in the way", he could have Louis to himself as a companion.

Just my thoughts.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFFSE!  In this community we strive to provide evidence-based results.  Although you do answer the questions, this does seem to be your opinion, although grounded on a reasonable basis.  I feel this would be better as a comment, a privilege you will unlock once you gain sufficient reputation.  Best of luck on this site!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Armand wants Louis for himself, and Claudia is the only thing that would prevent Louis from being devoted to Armand.  Therefore, he conveniently waits until Claudia is dead before rescuing Louis.

Comment: I think 'Leader' might be a bit misleading.  The coven was more like a wolf pack or a pirate crew. Armand could lead, but if the coven wanted something he couldn't stop them. Also, the creation of Claudia WAS a monstrous thing to do even if they were monsters and he probably felt it was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Stop them from killing her?! Well, in the book it's pretty clear Armand kills Claudia himself. He does it 'cause he wants Louis all for him and it gets obvious, even after Armand mentally influencing Louis to transform Madeleine, that Louis will never leave Claudia. 
 Armand thought Louis would get over it with time, and even tells Louis this, but Louis gradually becomes cold about him and everything else.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Any chance you could provide book quotes to support this answer?